# Universal Example for Angular 1.x Version

Tags: angularjs, isomorphic-javascript

I researched but found any result for this subject. I want to learn that how can I achive an UJ system with Angular 1.x version. Is there any example or guide? I found lost of example for Angular 2 but my project is run on Angular 1.x. And I couldn't change it.

Comment: This has very simple explanation. Because Universal is for Angular 2. It is hard to ignore this because it is said everywhere in library descriptions. The framework should be written with isomorphism in mind in order to do server-side renders. AngularJS wasn't.

Comment: @estus is there any way adapt it to AngularJS 1.x

Comment: No, there's no way, that's the point. If you're interested in doing this in A1 for SEO purposes, stick to prerendering the page with headless browser (Render.io/Prerender/whatever).

Comment: @estus Yes, SEO is one of the reasons, we have performance issue, I made a partial serverside rendering but it is not enough, also used prerender.io service for google

Comment: I guess you have no other options but to keep doing that. Btw, Universal isn't ready for production in Angular 2. It is being refactored to be usable in Angular 4.